# User defined R function to drop rows with 3 (or more) NAs in different data frames?

Tags: r, function

Is there a way to create a user defined function so I don't have to keep typing the same lines of code over and over?

I have one data frame containing the raw data and I have separate data frames for each measure that I'm using. The lines of code I am writing over and over again is this:

```
df1Final <- df1[rowSums(is.na(df1)) < 3, ]

df2Final <- df2[rowSums(is.na(df2)) < 3, ]

df3Final <- df3[rowSums(is.na(df3)) < 3, ]
```

I am using separate data frames and not the raw data frame because I only want to remove people if they have 3 or more missing cells in a measure.

I would also like to rename the df1, df2, df3, etc. to include "Final" at the end. I've tried this user defined function below but it doesn't work like I want it to (and it doesn't allow me to have "Final" at the end of the data frame name.

```
missingData <- function(df) {
  df <- df[rowSums(is.na(df)) < 3, ]

}
```

Thank you!

Edit: I have tried searching for a solution already but have yet to find one!

Comment: you need to `return(df)`

Comment: btw, if you put you data frames in a list, then you can use `lapply()` and won't have to copy and paste the function call

Comment: @shs I'm not sure what you mean. Do you mean something like this?

`listOfDfs <- list(df1, df2, df3)`
`lapply(listOfDfs, missingData)`

Comment: in a narrow sense, yes

Comment: in a larger sense, you would not want to construct the list by enumerating existing objects. You would want to have a list-based workflow from the start. If you read you dfs from separate files, it is good to import them into a list by applying the read function over a vector of file names. If you got them by splitting another data frame you would want to do the split in a way that returns a list. Putting similar objects into a list to begin with will allow you to streamline your code a lot

Answer (score 1):

Below a function `remove_cases` that does what you are looking for.
Let's first generate a `reprex`:

```
set.seed(1)

# generate some data
n_sample <- 100
d <- data.frame(x1 = rnorm(n_sample),
                x2 = rnorm(n_sample),
                x3 = rnorm(n_sample),
                x4 = rnorm(n_sample),
                x5 = rnorm(n_sample))

# function to column-wise generate missing values in data frame d
create_missings <- function(data, prob) {
  x <- replicate(ncol(data), rbinom(nrow(data), 1, prob))
  for(k in 1:ncol(data)) {
    data[, k] <- ifelse(x[, k] == 1, NA, data[,k])
  }
  data
}
my_data <- create_missings(data = d, prob = 0.5)
```

```
> head(my_data, 3)
          x1          x2        x3        x4       x5
1         NA          NA 0.4094018        NA 1.074441
2         NA  0.04211587        NA -1.047298       NA
3 -0.8356286 -0.91092165        NA  1.971337       NA
```

Now we need a function that removes all rows in `my_data` that contain ≥3 missing values.

```
remove_cases <- function(data, threshold = 3) {
  data <- data[which(rowSums(apply(data, 2, is.na)) < threshold),]
  data
}
my_data_updated <- remove_cases(my_data)
```

```
> table(rowSums(apply(my_data, 2, is.na)))

 0  1  2  3  4  5 
 1 26 28 32 12  1

> table(rowSums(apply(my_data_updated, 2, is.na)))

 0  1  2 
 1 26 28
```

We can easily apply `remove_cases` to a list of multiple data frames:

```
# create a list of 3 data frames with missings values
n_DFs <- 3
my_list <- replicate(n_DFs, create_missings(data = d, prob = 0.5), simplify = FALSE)
names(my_list) <- paste0('data_frame', 1:n_DFs, '_Final') # could assign names to each data frame

# apply function to each data frame
my_list_updated <- lapply(my_list, remove_cases, threshold = 2)  # max 1 missing per row
```

```
> lapply(my_list_updated, '[', 1:2, )
$data_frame1_Final
         x1        x2        x3         x4        x5
2 1.3431021 1.3677606  1.432408 -0.8008215        NA
3 0.9971683 0.1690414 -1.165338  0.4024705 0.6015763

$data_frame2_Final
          x1         x2         x3         x4         x5
3  0.9971683  0.1690414 -1.1653384  0.4024705  0.6015763
10 1.4148149 -1.2062871  0.8261034 -0.5110926 -0.9430766

$data_frame3_Final
           x1        x2        x3         x4         x5
7  -0.4642686 0.9899615  1.679337         NA -1.6729937
13  0.5839333        NA -1.329332 -0.3892703  0.2379008
```

If you would like to return the data frames in `my_list_updated` to the environment, simply run `list2env(my_list_updated, globalenv())`.

```
> grep('^dat', ls(), value = TRUE)
[1] "data_frame1_Final" "data_frame2_Final" "data_frame3_Final"
```